# Is there a Pythonic way to map a dictionary to another dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary, say `d = {-1: 10, 0: 20, 1: 30, 2: 40}` where the key k is some label and the value corresponds to the number of counts. I have some function `f(x)`, lets take `f(x)=|x|` and I want to make another dictionary `d2` such that `d2 = {f(x): #counts f(x)}` for all values of `x` that are keys in the original dictionary. Note that f is not injective so `f(-1)=f(1)`. Is there a (Pythonic) way to do this without explicitly looping and constructing `d2` from scratch?

In the example, the desired dictionary would be `d2 = {1: 40, 0:20, 2:40}`

Edit: my current solution

```
def map_dictionary(d, f):
    d2 = {}
    for k in d:
        if f(k) in d2:
            d2[f(k)] += d[k]
        else:
            d2[f(k)] = d[k]
    return d2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one idea is to use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {-1: 10, 0: 20, 1: 30, 2: 40}
f = abs
d2 = defaultdict(int)
for k, v in d.items():
    d2[f(k)] += v

print(d2)  # defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {1: 40, 0: 20, 2: 40})
```

`defaultdict(int)` will return `0` (which is what `int()` returns) for any key that does not exist yet.

---

UPDATE after you updated your question. no, there is no way to do this without looping (you absolutely **have** to look at the keys) - but there is a way to do it without creating a fresh dictionary (here for the special case `f = abs` only; it will depend on your `f` whether or not this approach works:

```
d = {-1: 10, 0: 20, 1: 30, 2: 40}

neg_keys = []
for k, v in d.items():
    if k < 0:
        neg_keys.append(k)
        d[-k] = d.get(-k, 0) + v

for k in neg_keys:
    del d[k]

print(d)  # {0: 20, 1: 40, 2: 40}
```

note that python forbids `del` in the first loop (for a good reason! `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`).

Answer (score 1):

`collections.Counter` can do this without adding anything:

```
from collections import Counter

d = {-1: 10, 0: 20, 1: 30, 2: 40}

d2 = Counter([abs(x) for x, y in d.items() for i in range(y)])
print(d2)  # Counter({1: 40, 2: 40, 0: 20})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/).

```py
def f(x):
    return abs(x)

d = {-1: 10, 0: 20, 1: 30, 2: 40}

d2 = { 
    f(key): d[f(key)] + d[key] if 
    f(key) != key and f(key) in d.keys() 
    else d[key]
    for key in sorted( d.keys(), reverse=True ) 
}

print(d2)
#{2: 40, 1: 40, 0: 20}
```

Comment: Edited my answer because the first draft was incorrect.